# Environment text in colour

Tags: color

I want to have the ability to colour the text using an optional argument (defaulted to orange).  Although `Something Something` should not be coloured.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Statement}{O{}}
  {
    Something Something
  }
  { \vspace{0.3cm} }

\begin{document}

\begin{Statement}
  This text is displayed in color.
\end{Statement}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\NewDocumentEnvironment{Statement}{O{orange}}
  {\color{#1}`

Comment: I would need to reset the colour to the original after the environment ends.

Comment: No you would not, environments are groups, everything resets.

Comment: All is very well then.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify Orange as the default in `O{}`

[image]

```
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Statement}{O{orange}}
  {%
    Something Something \color{#1}%
  }
  { \vspace{0.3cm} }

\begin{document}

\begin{Statement}
  This text is displayed in color.
\end{Statement}

Black
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by David Carlisle, an environment is a group. `\color{}` won't affect the text after `\end{statement}` closing marker.

If you want a default color in orange, you only have to declare it in the definition and use `\color{#1}` to apply the chosen color (if not, it will be orange).

See here :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{statement}[1][orange]%
{%
    \color{#1}% other stuff to apply at the start of the environment
}{%
    %%%Stuff here to apply at the end
}
\begin{document}
    This is normal text.
    \begin{statement}
        This text is displayed in color. Default is orange.
    \end{statement}
    
    This is normal text.
    
    \begin{statement}[purple]
        This text is displayed in purple.
    \end{statement}
    
    This is normal text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answers the question as the OP wanted some black text in the begin text, which you've  removed.